# Docker running Windows applications

Tags: .net, windows, docker, virtualization

I understand Docker to be a containerization tool, with a limited set of APIs so as to be platform agnostic. I am trying to understand what limitations it places on typical Windows development. For example, does it limit access only to write to a file system (and therefore rules out applications that write to the registry)? Is there a level of complexity where Dock is not suitable (but then again I heard that MSSQL will be supported on docker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really broad, and hard to answer definitively, but a few specific points in it can be addressed.

> I understand Docker to be a containerization tool, with a limited set of APIs so as to be platform agnostic.

It's platform agnostic in a sense that you could run a container on CentOS, Ubuntu, or any other Linux distribution, but you can't run a Linux container on Windows natively, or a Windows container on Linux natively. [Introducing Docker for Windows Server 2016](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/dockerforws2016/) is a good place to start with information regarding Windows containers.

---

> For example, does it limit access only to write to a file system (and therefore rules out applications that write to the registry)?

Based on [this MSDN FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/faq), no *(emphasis mine)*

> Windows Server Containers are a lightweight operating system virtualization method used to separate applications or services from other services running on the same container host. **To enable this, each container has its own view of the operating system, processes, file system, registry, and IP addresses.**

For example, dockerfile for [SQL Server Express image](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/manage/windows-containers/mssql-server-2014-express-windows/dockerfile#L27-L29) modifies the registry.

---

> Is there a level of complexity where Dock is not suitable

The question isn't about complexity but about availability of APIs. This is also from the above mentioned Docker for Windows Server 2016

> With the exception of GUI apps and apps requiring Windows Remote Desktop, most apps that run on Windows Server can be dockerized to run in an image based on microsoft/windowsservercore with minimal effort.

Comment: One can run Linux containers on Windows 10.

Comment: @Naikrovek Linux containers on Windows 10 run inside a Linux virtual machine. They don't share the kernel with the Windows host.

Answer (score 5):

Note: since then, you have "[**How to run lightweight Windows Containers on Windows 10**](https://stefanscherer.github.io/how-to-run-lightweight-windows-containers-on-windows-10/)" (January 2019, 2+ years later), from **[Stefan Scherer](https://twitter.com/stefscherer)**.

It does point out that, with the latest release of Docker Desktop (2.0.0.2+) on Windows 10 1809 you now can run Windows Containers in process isolation mode

> In the past process isolation was only possible with Windows Server.
>   The Windows 10 operating system uses the same kernel, but with different settings.
>   With this pull request [`moby/moby` PR 38000](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/38000) that got merged into Docker 18.09.1 it is now possible to use it on Windows 10 as well.
>
> - You can start more Windows Containers on your machine as they consume less resources
> - Containers normally start faster than in hyperv isolation mode
> - You can "see" the isolated processes and what they are doing
>
> Especially for developers this is a great enhancement, because you now can use tools like Task Manager, Process Monitor and others to inspect your container processes from the host
>
> The only caveat using the process isolation mode is that the Windows base image that is used for a Docker image must match the kernel of your Windows 10 machine.
>
> Open up a PowerShell terminal and start a Windows container with this command
>
> ```
> docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --isolation=process chocolateyfest/appetizer:1.0.0
> ```

[image: https://stefanscherer.github.io/content/images/2019/01/windows-10-process-isolation.png]

> As you can see in the screen shot you can see the node.exe process in the Task Manager.
>   If you have the Sysinternals Process Monitor installed you also can see what the containerized process is doing.
>
> This is great when you create an own Docker image from your or a 3rd-party app and something doesn't work as expected or the exe file just doesn't want to start inside the container.

Comment: This is a gem of an answer, very underrated.  Thanks.